# Insert VLOOKUP into cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I cannot seem to get this to work.
I want to put this vlookup formula into cell B10, looking up A10, but it gives me a NAME? value every time, as it comes out as 'A10' in the actual formula, instead of A10. Can anyone help? Here's my code:

```
    Range("B10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(A10,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,0)"
```

Comment: change `.FormulaR1C1` to `.Formula`.  The `.FormulaR1C1` is looking for R1C1 notation.

Comment: Also, [don't use `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). A quick fix, with @ScottCraner's suggestion, is this: `Range("B10").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A10,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,0)"`

Comment: You guys are the best-- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @scottCraner said, you need it in this format:

```
Range("B10").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A10,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,0)"
```

Comment: @reggie86 mark correct if that is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("AJ2").NumberFormat = "General"

Range("AJ2").Select

ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'[" & SRCActiveBook & "]" & SRCActiveSheet & "'!$A:$A" & ",1,0)"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.